# Can a mobile web app be notified of a touch event without handling (overriding) the event?

Tags: dom, mobile, web-applications, touch

I've spent 20 hours or so in the last two days trying to find a way to do this.  I spent most of that time using hammer.js (javacript version) and can see how the library handles touch events (pinch, specifically) but every example I've tried kills the default.

Events are NOT my strong point.  Most of my knowledge (limited as it is) was learned in VB.net, which was quite a few years ago.  What I recall is that the handlers would have to return a value.  One could either return null (effectively killing the system default action) or return the event arguments so as to not disrupt the native action.  I can't find anything like that with mobile web apps.

Specifically, I'm looking for something like document.onScaleChange.  I'm grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm embarrassed.  I was making this out to be WAY more complicated than it is.  There may be a better way, if so, please chime in.

The first method I found to work wasn't very elegant, but it served the purpose and led to what seems to be a better way.  Part of the problem is I haven't been able to find very comprehensive references to the DOM. After running across this link, [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) (in case others are having the same trouble as I). `var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 500);

```js
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 500);

function myCallback(){
  // Your code here
}
```

The better way was just to listen for the 'touchend' event.

```js
  window.addEventListener("touchend", function() {
 /* code here */
});
```

It couldn't have been more simple.  If there are any problems using the last method, please let me know.  I had seen similar methods before but when I tried them, they wouldn't work.  Maybe I just messed up the syntax or something.